# Why does the regex (aba?)+ not match with abab?

Tags: regex

Given `(aba?)+` as the Regex and `abab` is the string.

Why does it only matches `aba`?

Since the last a in the regex is optional, isn't `abab` a match as well?

tested on https://regex101.com/

Comment: `aba` is matched first, then `b` remains to be consumed, but it does not match, thus `abab` is OK. Maybe you want to use `(ab(?=a|$))+` or `(ab(?![^a]))+`

Comment: Just [see this debugging page](https://regex101.com/r/n53vxV/1/debugger), you will see why.

Comment: So, all you need are anchors, `^` and `$`. There is absolutely no need in lazy `??`. Greediness is of no importance here, I already mentioned that in another comment. [`^(aba?)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/hObylO/1) will behave the same as `^(aba??)+$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `(aba?)+` only matches `aba` out of `abab` is greedy matching: The optional `a` in the first loop is tested before the group is tested again, and matches. Therefore, the remaining string is `b`, which does not match `(aba?)` again.

If you want to turn off greedy matching for this optional `a`, use  `a??`, or write your regex differently.

Comment: When you use `a??` at the end of the pattern, it always matches an empty string, the `a` is not even tested. This has nothing to do with greediness anyway.

Comment: Yeah aba is not even matched anymore...

Comment: Unless you use beginning / ending string anchors `^(aba??)+$` @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @revo As I said, the `a??` *at the end of the pattern*, and in your (not OP) `^(aba??)+$` regex, `a??` is not at the end. This answer is not answering the question. DonCallisto's was correct, no idea why the answer got deleted.

Comment: I find this answer a straightforward explanation. That's totally it.

Answer (score 0):

Since (aba?)+ is greedy, your pattern tries to match as much as possible. And since it first matches "aba", the remaining "b" is not matched.

Try the non-greedy version (it will match the first and second "ab"'s):

```
$ echo "abab" | grep -Po "(aba?)+"
aba
$ echo "abab" | grep -Po "(aba??)+"
abab
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct regex for this is:

```
^(aba??)+$
```

and not `(aba??)+` as discussed with @WiktorStribizew and YSelf.

Comment: Actually the OP does not specify explicitly if he wants to match the full input or just (any number of) parts from it. If the latter then usage of `^` and `$` would be incorrect.